# docker inspect not revealing IP Address of the application

Tags: .net, docker, dockerfile, devops, docker-container

I am building ASP.NET web API application using docker on windows 2016 server.

This is how my dockerfile looks:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet-framework:4.7.2-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /app

# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.sln .
COPY TestWebAPI/*.csproj ./TestWebAPI/
COPY TestWebAPI/*.config ./TestWebAPI/
RUN nuget restore

# copy everything else and build app
COPY TestWebAPI/. ./TestWebAPI/
WORKDIR /app/TestWebAPI
RUN msbuild /p:Configuration=Release


FROM microsoft/iis:10.0.14393.206

SHELL ["powershell"]


FROM microsoft/aspnet:4.7.2 AS runtime
WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot
COPY --from=build /app/TestWebAPI/. ./

RUN Remove-Website -Name 'Default Web Site'
RUN New-Website -Name 'TestWebApi' -Port 80 \
    -PhysicalPath 'c:\inetpub\wwwroot' -ApplicationPool '.NET v4.5'
EXPOSE 80

CMD Write-Host IIS Started... ; \
    while ($true) { Start-Sleep -Seconds 3600 }
```

Then I executed following commands to build and run container:

```
docker image build --tag testwebapi --file .\Dockerfile .

docker container run --detach --publish 80 testwebapi
```

Then I ran docker inspect with sandbox id of the container:

```
 docker inspect 5638e
```

[image]

It showed my info about container but IP address column key was empty. **How can I find the IP address and what is the issue here?**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter: that IP address, were it to exist, is useless for most purposes.  You can't reliably reach it from outside of Docker space, and from another container Docker provides a DNS service so that the container is reachable by its `docker run --name` name.

If you're trying to make a connection from something on the host (maybe a browser) to the container, your `--publish 80` option causes Docker to pick a port and forward it to port 80 in the container.  That should be in the `docker inspect` output ([under "NetworkSettings"](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/inspect/#find-a-specific-port-mapping)).  It's more typical to pick the port yourself, though: if you `--publish 8765:80` then you know it's port 8765 on the host.  (This is very often abbreviated to `-p`.)

You shouldn't routinely need to run `docker inspect`.  It won't usually tell you anything you don't already know from the `docker run` command.